Selenium click() method issues with XPATH
I'm trying to click a button with selenium using a simple automated login screen test.
I am running this test on 2 separate accounts with 2 a little bit different login screens.
The first one works as expected, where I can just locate the button with "SPAN" (because thats how it is set up):
<button mat-raised-button="" fisstyle="" color="primary" class="mat-focus-indicator mat-raised-button mat-button-base mat-primary ng-star-inserted">
  <span class="mat-button-wrapper"> Sign in </span>
  <span matripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-button-ripple"></span>
  <span class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></span>
</button>

However, the second login page has a little bit different setup:
<button mat-raised-button="" fisstyle="" color="primary" class="mat-focus-indicator mat-raised-button mat-button-base mat-primary ng-star-inserted">Sign in</button>

The first page works using this code:
sm.click(driver, "//span[text()=' Sign in ']")

but with the second one Selenium has trouble picking it up.
Any suggestions?
I tried adding pauses before the click since I assumed that this might be caused by the button element not being available before being pressed but that's not the case. Experimented with for example this code for the button without a span:
sm.click(driver, '//button[@class="mat-focus-indicator mat-raised-button mat-button-base mat-primary ng-star-inserted"')

but it didn't work

Use this XPath - //button[text()='Sign in'] to locate the element in the second login page.

maybe it has some extra spaces or new lines - try //button[contains(text(), 'Sign in')]

without access to this page we can't see what can makes problem, and we can't test solutions. Maybe you have button in <iframe> and you have to use driver.switch_to.frame(...) because Selenium treats frame as separate page.

If you are looking for a single locator that will find both, you can use the XPath below
//button[contains(.,'Sign in')]

If you are looking for one locator for each element, you already have the first one so the second one would be.
//button[text()='Sign in']

There are a couple differences,

In the first element, the "Sign in" string is not directly in the BUTTON tag but instead is in the SPAN. The "Sign in" string itself actually contains a space on either side, as you already identified.
In the second element, the "Sign in" text is actually in the BUTTON element itself and does not contain the padding spaces.

Both . and text() XPath functions search through text nodes but do it differently. See this SO answer for a detailed description of the difference with examples.
